# How to format my date from 1.1.2011 to 01.01.2011

Tags: jquery, datepicker, format

I have a small script for two datepickers to calculate the nights and that the user cant select an earlier date then today, no i have trouble to display the right formatted date,

if i visit the page it shows me only the arrivaldate like i need, after selecting the departuredate it shows me the right formatted departuredate, how could i fix this?

```
    var my2Date = new Date();
    var pretty2Date = my2Date.getDate() + '.' + (my2Date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + my2Date.getFullYear();
    $("#abreise").val(pretty2Date);

    $("#anreise, #abreise").datepicker({
        onSelect: DatePicked,
        minDate: new Date()
    });
    $("#nacht").change(DatePicked);
    DatePicked();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the date format to: `dd.mm.yy`

Comment: the dateformat is already set to dd.mm.yy, thats my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use http://www.datejs.com/ date library to format date and time in any shape and form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you make your dates "pretty":

```
var prettyDate = myDate.getDate() + '.' 
    + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '.' 
    + myDate.getFullYear();
```

Should become:

```
function padNumber(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        number = "0" + number;
    }
    return number;
}
var prettyDate = padNumber(myDate.getDate()) + '.' 
    + padNumber((myDate.getMonth()+1)) + '.' 
    + myDate.getFullYear();
```

However, I would advance you to use a plugin for this kind of stuff: http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js
If you use this, then you can just format all your Date-instances like this:

```
var prettyDate = myDate.format("dd.mm.yyyy");
```

This is much more maintainable.